# How can I store MySQL database results in R dataframe

Tags: mysql, r

I'm creating a shiny app in which I need to create a plot from the data returned by the sql query. Now I'm trying to do this by creating a dataframe and storing the value in it. When I run this shiny app it gives me an error `cannot coerce class "structure("MySQLResult", package = "RMySQL")" to a data.frame`

How can I store the database query result in a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with `dplyr`, you can use `dplyr::collect()` to save query results into the data frame. Please visit [RStudio website on working with databases](http://db.rstudio.com) to see more ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got your question right so correct me if I am wrong.
This is what am thinnking:

```
frame <- dbGetQuery(con, statement= paste("select col1
                                      from table1")) `
```

`con` is your dB connection.
Convert `year` into a dataframe:
`year_new<-data.frame(year)`

If I have not answered your question, let me know.
Also kindly post how you are doing it so it will be easier to understand what the problem is.`